# True/False question in Propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to Prove of disprove this statement

If $S$ $\cup$ $\{a\}\models{b} $ and  $   S$ $\cup$ $\{\neg a\}$$\models{b}$ then $S$ $\models b$ 
Looks to me like a True statement , but found it hard for me to explain.
I would like to get some hint.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction.

Assume not, i.e. there is a *valuation* $v$ such that:

> $v(\sigma)=$**t**, for all $\sigma \in S$, and $v(b)=$**f**.

But either $v(a)=$**t** or $v(\lnot a)=$**t**, according to the properties of valuations.

Thus, we have a valuation $v$ such that either:

> $v(\sigma)=$**t**, for all $\sigma \in S$, and $v(a)=$**t** and $v(b)=$**f**, contradicting the fact that $S \cup \{ a \} \vDash b$

or:

> $v(\sigma)=$**t**, for all $\sigma \in S$, and $v(\lnot a)=$**t** and $v(b)=$**f**, contradicting the fact that $S \cup \{ \lnot a \} \vDash b$.